# how to get html table row data into a dialog box to edit

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, dialog

i have a users.jsp page which contains the html table so when i click on edit button a pop window should be opened with data so the form is in another file editDialog.jsp which i want to submit... so i tried many ways but i couldnt find the solution...

```
<div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
                class="display example" id="example1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Login</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Created</th>
                        <th>Last Modified</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="users" varStatus="loopStatus">
                        <tr id="${users.user_id}">
                            <td>${users.login_name}</td>
                            <td>${users.account_status eq 1 ? "Enable" : "Disable"}</td>
                            <td>${users.created_at}, ${users.created_by}</td>
                            <td>${users.updated_at}, ${users.updated_by}</td>
                            <td><input class="button" type="button" name="updateRows" value='Edit' onclick="editUserData(${users.user_id})" /></td>

                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

editDialog.jsp

so the dialog should populate only loginId and account status and userId should be hidden
and account_status is the editable value... i stuck up here need help....

```
<div id="editDialog" title="Edit user" style="display: none">
    <form:form action="users.do" method="POST" commandName="users"
        id="editForm">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td id="loginId"><form:input path="login_name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hide">
                    <td>UserId:</td>
                    <td id="userId"><form:input path="user_id" readonly="true" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Status:</td>
                    <td id="statusId"><form:radiobutton path="account_status"
                            value="1" /> Enable <form:radiobutton path="account_status"
                            value="0" /> Disable</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>CsId:</td>
                    <td id="csId"><form:input path="cs_id" readonly="true" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hide">
                    <td>Created_at:</td>
                    <td id="createdAtId"><form:input path="created_at"
                            readonly="true" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hide">
                    <td>Created_by:</td>
                    <td id="createdById"><form:input path="created_by"
                            readonly="true" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hide">
                    <td>Updated_at:</td>
                    <td id="updatedAtId"><form:input path="updated_at"
                            readonly="true" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hide">
                    <td>Updated_by:</td>
                    <td id="updatedById"><form:input path="updated_by"
                            readonly="true" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit">
                        <input id="addCancel" type="button" value="Cancel"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by having one form hidden in a div and whenever the user clicks on the edit button copy the necessary information to the form element and then show it as dialog and allow the user to save / cancel it. On save submit the form data as Ajax request.

Comment: but you have to post it to server for updating the user information

Comment: yes but first while i click on edit the dialog form should have the html row content then i modify the data in dialog(editdialog.jsp) when i click on update data will go to controller... right? my question is like how to get the html row data to dialog form